# Find intersection of numpy float arrays

Tags: python, numpy

How can I find the intersection of two numpy float arrays?:

```
a = np.arange(2, 3, 0.1)
b = np.array([2.3, 2.4, 2.5])
out_data = np.intersect1d(a, b)
```

the result is

```
out_data -> ndarray: []
```

Comment: Can you describe the problem a little more clearly?  What you gave here is the correct answer: the two lists have no items in common.

Comment: @Prune Maybe I am seeing things but looks to me that 2.3, 2.4, 2.5 are common to both a and b: a -> ndarray: [ 2.   2.1  2.2  2.3  2.4  2.5  2.6  2.7  2.8  2.9], b -> ndarray: [ 2.3  2.4  2.5]

Comment: Sorry; I didn't explain well enough; I deal with round-off problems all day.

I strongly suspect that you get a series of values more like
[2.0, 2.09999999998, 2.1999999999997, ...]

Have you tried printing your generated list with high precision?  From what I recall, intersect1d does not have a precision modifier for "almostEquals".  You may have to write that yourself.  Another way is to round each list element to the same precision, such as 5 decimal places, and then do the intersection.

Comment: @Prune I thought the reason was probably something related to rounding, I added a routine below to overcome this, but found Dan Patterson's suggestion more succinct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting my comments in function form (assuming both lists are sorted, which you should do ahead of time):

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import islice

def findOverlap(self, a, b, rtol = 1e-05, atol = 1e-08):
    ovr_a = []
    ovr_b = []
    start_b = 0
    for i, ai in enumerate(a):
        for j, bj in islice(enumerate(b), start_b, None):
            if np.isclose(ai, bj, rtol=rtol, atol=atol, equal_nan=False):
                ovr_a.append(i)
                ovr_b.append(j)
            elif bj > ai: # (more than tolerance)
                break # all the rest will be farther away
            else: # bj < ai (more than tolerance)
                start_b += 1 # ignore further tests of this item
    return (ovr_a, ovr_b)
```

EDIT: getting rid of `equal_nan` -- if you're going to sort you may as well ditch the nans

EDIT: using islice instead of array slice

EDIT: fixed bug

Comment: NB: this will still be quadratic if everything in both lists overlap within tolerance. But in most cases I shouldn't think this would happen.

Comment: The ovr_a return obviously represents the indexes of the matched vales relative to list a, but it's not clear to me what ovr_b with value [0, 2, 3] represents.

Comment: I just edited to use islice instead -- it makes the index clearer and also avoids the case when b[start_b:] would return a copy

Comment: @JohnMoeller could you check my update to see if it not returning the same thing.  I am wondering if linspace performs the tolerance test by default, but my reading of C code in the SciPy documents doesn't suggest so.  Perhaps this is a coincidence with this given sequence.

Comment: @DanPatterson I'm afraid I'm not sure what you're asking. I ran your code below and got the same output that you did.

Comment: @JohnMoeller I just wanted to confirm that np.linspace is a safer alternative to np.arange when floats are involved, since I couldn't find anything specific when searching the documentation or online

Comment: @DanPatterson Well, I think it's safer just to assume that floats aren't going to be exactly equal. It's much better to test with a function like `isclose`.

Answer (score 4):

Because of the way floats work, in your example a[3] is not 2.3, but 2.3000000000000003. This is because 0.1 does not have an exact representation in IEEE double precision floats. The `intersect1d` method in numpy is really only well suited for integers. To solve this, you should implement your own method that takes in a tolerance to decide if two floats are sufficiently close.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a vectorized approach using [`NumPy's broadcasting capability`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
tol = 1e-5 # tolerance
out = b[(np.abs(a[:,None] - b) < tol).any(0)]
```

Sample run -

```
In [31]: a
Out[31]: array([ 2. ,  2.1,  2.2,  2.3,  2.4,  2.5,  2.6,  2.7,  2.8,  2.9])

In [32]: b
Out[32]: array([ 2.3 ,  2.4 ,  2.5 ,  2.25,  2.1 ])

In [33]: tol = 1e-5 # tolerance

In [34]: b[(np.abs(a[:,None] - b) < tol).any(0)]
Out[34]: array([ 2.3,  2.4,  2.5,  2.1])
```

Comment: In fact you can use `b[np.isclose(a[:,None],b).any(0)]` as well

Comment: I should also add that it's much faster than my method.

Comment: @JohnMoeller Oh yes! That should work too, thanks! :)

Comment: Came across this nice solution. However when the two arrays are quite large (>10000) it is painfully slow. I am looking for a parallelized solution but I do not know where to start. Multithreading/Multiprocessing package? Numba? What would be a suitable approach?

Answer (score 0):

The following routine will return the indexes of common values within specified tolerance(s) relative to list a.

```
def findOverlap(self, a, b, rtol = 1e-05, atol = 1e-08, equal_nan = False):
    overlap_indexes = []
    for i, item_a in enumerate(a):
        for item_b in b:
            if np.isclose(item_a, item_b, rtol = rtol, atol = atol, equal_nan = equal_nan):
                overlap_indexes.append(i)
    return overlap_indexes
```

eg

```
a = np.arange(2, 3, 0.1).tolist()
b = np.array([2.3, 2.4, 2.5]).tolist()
self.findOverlap(a, b)

-> overlap_indexes:[3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: If `item_a` is currently 2.7, you know that when you searched `b` against 2.6 that nothing in `b` was close, so you can abandon the search. Likewise, when you start searching `a`, you only have to test against the first element of `b` until you get close. 

You can actually apply the same reasoning inside the inner loop, and break as soon as you fail when `item_b` is greater than `item_a`. Even further, you don't have to start at the beginning of `b` when you failed last time and `item_b` is less than `item_a`.

Comment: Also note that this is easily modified to return the overlapping values, rather than the indices.

Comment: @Prune Yes, though John Moeller's routine was more efficient and I just used that and modified the ovr_a.append(i) to over_a.append(ai) to return the values. That solved the issue I was having and was most helpful. As for the best solution, I would say Divakar's solution wins - it's succinct and fast.

Comment: No problem here, but it's nice that you added the explanation.  The important thing is that we got you moving again, and that you have choices.